# How to develop using GIT on database driven website project?

Tags: wordpress, git

I like to use a simple Git workflow for static web sites but I build Joomla and Wordpress sites a semi-regular basis too. However I am at a loss as to how to use Git with with database driven site development.

For a static site I would 'Push' to dev.websitename.com, then push to www.websitename.com once the dev site checks out. How would I mimic that process with database driven site like wordpress or joomla.

Thanks in advance for you insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use Git with your website code, such as changes to your WordPress theme/plugin, exactly as you would if you are developing a static website.

However, you wouldn't use it for your database. Git provides version control for *code*, while WordPress and Joomla already manage *content* stored in the database. Plus, Git wouldn't understand a database, so it wouldn't have any advantage over a periodic backup, which you should already be doing. Take a look at [running a dev copy of your site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress) for how to download your database directly from your server.

By the way, if you use Git with WordPress/Joomla, you should add e.g. cache, logs, tmp to .gitignore. There are also lots of tutorials out there--try searching e.g. http://google.com/search?q=wordpress+git.

Comment: Okay that all makes perfect sense. Now I just need to merge those two separate process into simple command maybe with handy little script.

Answer (score 0):

In addition Chris, you may want to embark on your Git workflow without the handy script approach (at least initially).  The script approach and using Git hooks can sure seem sexy (well, because they are) and handy too, but initially why not go with a more manual cmd line approach, which will also help you familiarize yourself with Git.

Once you've got your repo setup (GitHub, Bitbucket, somewhere else) and you've pushed your latest to it and are ready to deploy to production or staging, just login to your host and from wherever you've initialized the git repo (site root, example: /site) just do a:

```
git pull origin master
```

This will fetch and merge your code.  Good idea to test this on a dev/staging environment and if the merge goes well then do it in production.